# Regular Expression with wild character in the beginning-middle-end of the text

Tags: c#, regex

What regular expression should I use if I want to find a match based on following pattern:
`%abc%xyz%` where `%` is the wildcard character.

Words that would match are -

Hi**abc**Hello**xyz**Hee

Test1**abc**Test2**xyz**Test3

Thanks in advance. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: There are no wildcards in regular expressions. Do you want to match *non-whitespace characters 0 or more times* by your `%`? Also, what tag is correct: c# or nsregularexpression? Are these words part of larger text or individual strings?

Comment: @stribizhev: with wildcards, the OP means any kind of text I think. Why would whitespace not be allowed. If we are talking about text...

Comment: if your problem has been solved you can mark the answer that helped you most as accepted (green tick)

Answer (score 7):

In Short:

```
.*abc.*xyz.*
```

This matches all words containing first `"abc"` and then `"xyz"` (including your example words)

Comment: depending what he is doing he may or may not want greedy

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression is:

```
^[\s\S]*abc[\S\s]*xyz[\s\S]*$
```

With `[\s\S]` a box that contains all spacing characters `\s` and all non-spacing characters `\S`; in other words all characters.

If you don't want to include new lines, simply use:

```
^.*abc.*xyz.*$
```

The dot `.` matches nearly everything except new lines.

If you do **not** want to allow new lines, spaces, etc. either, one can use:

```
^\S*abc\S*xyz\S*$
```

## Example (on the `csharp` interactive shell)

```
$ csharp
Mono C# Shell, type "help;" for help

Enter statements below.
csharp> using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
csharp> Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[\s\S]*abc[\S\s]*xyz[\s\S]*$");
csharp> regex.Matches("HiabcHelloxyzHee");
{ HiabcHelloxyzHee }
csharp> regex.Matches("Test1abcTest2xyzTest3");
{ Test1abcTest2xyzTest3 }
csharp> regex.Matches("fooabcbar");             
{  }
csharp> regex.Matches("fooabcbarxyz");
{ fooabcbarxyz }
csharp> regex.Matches("fooabcbarxyz  dasd");
{ fooabcbarxyz  dasd }
csharp> regex.Matches("fooabc   barxyz  dasd");
{ fooabc   barxyz  dasd }
```